# How to get the right value using a join

Tags: mysql, join

This is driving me nuts, I'm sure it's rather simple but can't get it right.

Having a table holding ratevalues for different years:

```
Ratevaluetable

Year   Value A  Value B  Value C
2009     10      15       20
2010     12      18       22
2011     14      21       25
```

Then I have another persontable:

```
User    Time      Price
john    2010      value B
Tina    2009      Value C
Bill    2011      Value C
```

Now what I need is to join the 2 tables so that I get the value in the `Price` column substituted with the data from the `Ratevaluetable`.

I can join on time on year, but the I don't know how to join to the `Value` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with your current database schema. Joins connect tables by matching column values; what you propose to do here is match a column value with a column *name*, which is impossible.

What *would* be possible is:

```
Table ValueTypes:
Id    Description
1     Value A
2     Value B
3     Value C

Table RateValueTable:
Year     ValueTypeId     Value
2009     1               10
2009     2               15
2009     3               20

Table User:
User    Time      ValueTypeId
john    2009      2
```

Given the above schema, you could join `User` to `RateValueTable` in the obvious manner.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it's not really the best database design. You'd have to do a conditional statement to figure out which column of Ratevaluetable to get.

```
SELECT persontable.User, persontable.Time, CASE WHEN persontable.Price = 'value a' THEN `Ratevaluetable.Value A` WHEN persontable.Price = 'value b' THEN `Ratevaluetable.Value B` WHEN persontable.Price = 'value c' THEN `Ratevaluetable.Value C` AS 'price' FROM persontable, Ratevaluetable WHERE persontable.Time = Ratevaluetable.year
```